# manipulating .aspx file programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I was recently assigned a task of changing our asp.net web site localization to use custom resource provider (using sql database) instead of the default asrx resource files. Right now I'm chalenged with replacing hundreds of `meta:resourcekey="resource-key"` with `'<%$ Resources:[filename,]resource-key %>'` in our web site too many web pages. I want to do it programmatically.

first of all I'm not able to open .aspx files using XmlDocument, then I wonder how can I read meta:resource entries inside the aspx file as meta:resource is not any regular node attribute. any thoughts or example code how to solve this.
Thx.

**Note:** in the inserted `'<%$ Resources:[filename,]resource-key %>'` **filename** name sould be based on the aspx file name & **resource-key** on the control type and the resource value.

**exemple:** in UserPage.aspx page `<asp:Label id="uid" meta:resource="userName">` should be replaced with  `<asp:Label id="uid" Text='<%$ Resources:UserPage,LBL_userName_text %>'`.

Answer (score 2):

Html is not valid xml, so no wonder an XmlDocument didn't work. Especially with that `<%$ .. %>` syntax.

Why not read it as plain text and search for the string "meta:resourcekey"?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a programming answer, but a utility like [PowerGREP](http://www.powergrep.com/) may be a viable solution.